# LocalDateTime remove the milliseconds

Tags: java, database, date, java-8

I am working on java application where i am using Java 8.

I have integrated the database(multiple database Oracle, Mysql, Postgres) and where in DB i string the created date.

the date format in DB is - 2015-07-29 16:23:28.143

I fetch this from DB and set in Localdatetime object

```
myObj.setCreated(rs.getTimestamp("created").toLocalDateTime());
```

So here the issue is i don't want to show/send the millisecond in the response. i want to show/send date like 2015-07-29 16:23:28

I tried the formatter but it fails as it gives a string and i don't want to change the LocalDateTime object to String as this going to cause major change in all Java application.So want to find the solution

Can anybody know any solution to this?

Comment: Nope, that's not the format in those databases for their date-time data types. Date-time values in the database do not have an inherent format. The string representation you generate *from* the date-time value has a format.

Comment: By the way… (a) Do not use `java.sql.Timestamp`. Avoid the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes that were yeas ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* class defined in JSR 310. (b) For tracking "created" moments, use a column of a data type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (not `WITHOUT`). In JDBC 4.2, that maps to the Java class `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. In using `LocalDateTime`, you are discarding valuable information: the offset from UTC. Ex: `OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( "created" , OffsetDateTime.class).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );`

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Simply set them to `0`:

`myObj.setCreated(rs.getTimestamp("created").toLocalDateTime().withNano(0));`

Sample/proof:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class DateTimeSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println(ldt);
    System.out.println(ldt.withNano(0));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2015-07-30T16:29:11.684
2015-07-30T16:29:11
```

---

*Author's note: Although this is the accepted one, [Peter Lawrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31726586/4616087) is IMHO preferrable because it makes the intention more clear.*

Comment: This solution is working fine as it give the date without the milliseconds

Comment: There is a small notice. Make sure that you don't need seconds. In case you have 00 seconds in your LocalDateTime 2015-07-30T16:29:00.684  and you cut withNano(0) or truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS) you will get 2015-07-30T16:29 . Sometimes this is not the result that you expected.

Comment: Valid point. That is only an issue with `LocalDateTime.toString`, though. `LocalDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)` will print the seconds.

Answer (score 215):

## Truncate

You can drop anything less than seconds.

- Call [`LocalDateTime#truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).
- Specify granularity with [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

```java
ldt = ldt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: @NitinMurlidharGaikwad Can you explain "dont work" in a bit more detail?

Comment: if you try this still it give the millisecond, but if you print/put in string this time it don't show the millisecond

Comment: This answer worked well for me when comparing a LocalDateTime created in a test and then used to compare to a value in the database that rounds the milliseconds to the nearest second.

Comment: @Kaschwenk I think it's a bit clearer in terms of intent.

Comment: I suspect the OP didn't like the answer because you didn't explicitly write the line of code they wanted, which would have been this:
`myObj.setCreated(rs.getTimestamp("created").toLocalDateTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));`

Comment: Works for `Instant`, too

Comment: I like this more than the selected answer. The intention is clearer

Answer (score 8):

Providing code and logs to `Happy Family` comment at `Marvin` answer for those for whom STRING works,

!!! I as well fell into the same trap !!!

**Issue**:

`withNano(0)` and `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)` will also remove seconds if the seconds are as `:00` (At clock, seconds hand at 12 up straight)

Further Stretching Marvin's example output

```
2015-07-30T16:29:11.684
2015-07-30T16:29:11
2015-07-30T16:31 // for actual time 2015-07-30T16:31:00.684
2015-07-30T16:31 // for actual time 2015-07-30T16:31:00.888
```

**Above behaviour which could cause BUG:**

As you eliminate the nano seconds, if seconds turn up as `:00`, they skip from being printed

**RESOLUTION:**

```
public class WithNanoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(500);

            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
            System.out.println("truncate :::: " + LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(dtf));
            System.out.println("withNano :::: " + LocalDateTime.now().withNano(0).format(dtf));
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of logs

Logs using DateFormatter

[image: Logs using DateFormatter]

Logs WITHOUT DateFormatter (only using `truncate` or `withNano(0)`)

Observe the missing seconds here !

[image: Logs WITHOUT DateFormatter]

Comment: Well, the question was for *i dont want change the LocalDateTime object to String as this going to cause major change in all Java application.* You’re giving us a string.

Comment: @OleV.V. This is more of a warning I reflected here. Recently faced this at PROD. So thought its worthy for those, for whom STRING works :)

Comment: @OleV.V. As this truncation of seconds behaviour is not expected !

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for Edit :) . Would catch more precise audience now !

Comment: fwiw: The truncation is exactly what the Javadoc of the corresponding `toString` method explains. This is intended behaviour. If you want to have a specific format, use a formatter.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a wired bug we faced very recently. So to conversion purpose I personally prefer to set up the format then convert accordingly with `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
myObject.setEventStartTimestamp(dateTimeFormatter.format(eventStartTime));
```

Here, if you don't need the milliseconds then take it off form the pattern. It will provide the exact format you are looking for. Also if you want to set your local time you can choose your timezone like  `ZoneOffset.EST` or `ZoneOffset.MT` or `ZoneOffset.PST`

Comment: `ZoneOffset.EST`?? That and the other you mention don't exist in [the dcumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html). For good reasons since neither denotes a well-defined offset.

Comment: The bug is in your design: Inside your object you should not want to keep the time as a string, but simply as a date-time object such as an `Instant` ( `LocalDateTime` probably isn't the best choice since it cannot denote a point in time).

Comment: It's under import `java.time.ZoneOffset`  I think you are looking under `java.time.ZoneOffset`

Comment: Yes, that’s where I looked. Where should I look instead? (Did you say `java.time.ZoneOffset` instead of `java.time.ZoneOffset`??) In any case your offsets are nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to do this is :

```
setDateOfreport(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")));
```

This returns the output as a string, so all you need to do is parse the whole thing back in to a LocalDate object:

```
setDateOfreport(
        LocalDateTime.parse(
                LocalDateTime.now()
                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))));
```

This eliminates all the problems associated with truncating. I haven't set a timezone simply because I don't need one.

Comment: To me this feels a needless detour compared to truncating (it also takes more keystrokes and more CPU cycles, not that any of that matters). Also you necessarily *do* need a time zone. The `now()` method gives different results in different time zones, so it matters which one you use.