# How to avoid using milliseconds when using OffsetDateTime.now()

Tags: java, spring, rest-assured

I am using **OffsetDateTime.now()** to get the current date in UTC format and result includes milliseconds too. I don't want milliseconds to be sent . Is there a way i can remove Milliseconds from OffsetDateTime.now() without using split.

```
Current format: 2021-02-11T11:27:27.846871-08:00
Format i am looking: 2021-02-10T16:04:00-08:00
```

Comment: does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/31726418/6309111

Comment: By the way, those are microseconds, not milliseconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myOffsetDateTime.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )
```

## Details

The date-time classes such as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) are not strings. They do not have a format. Rather than thinking in terms of string manipulation, think in terms of the date-time logic.

The `OffsetDateTime` class offers a [`truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) method for setting smaller parts to zero. Pass a [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) to specify the granularity of your truncation. Specify `ChronoUnit.SECONDS` to set the fraction-of-second (a number of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)) to zero.

```
OffsetDateTime nowUtc = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
OffsetDateTime nowUtcTruncated = nowUtc.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```